# Set background color for Panorama Title

Tags: windows-phone-7

I would like to set the background color of the title of a panorama.  I have done this by creating a DataTemplate and setting it to the TitleTemplate.  I then set the background color as such:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="PanoramaTitleTemplate">
    <Grid Margin="0,50,0,0" Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" FontSize="133.333" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

The problem is that on the last page of the panorama, the color doesn't fill the whole area.  It ends where the text ends.  I've tried setting the grid to a longer width, but not only does that still not fill the screen, it affects the title scrolling as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the way the title is animated as part of the paralax effect.

You could write your own Panorama replacements but you'll find it much easier to add a separate image to the page instead of to the Panorama and add another item (probably a rectangle) in front of that which you can se to be the accent colour.

Comment: Sometimes the answer is just too simple to see.  I just put a filled rectangle behind the header and you wouldn't be able to tell the difference.  Not sure what you meant by "separate image", but I assume you meant if the pano had a background image, which mine doesn't.  Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Create a DataTemplate for your Panorama Title and set the width of the TextBlock (items * 480):

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="PanoramaTitleTemplate">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="#FF990000" Margin="-10 76 0 -9"> <!-- default 10,-76,0,9 -->
    <Image x:Name="logoImage" Source="/ApplicationIcon.png" Margin="10 0 30 0" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="1920" Height="40" FontSize="20"/> 
  </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```